# What are some scripting methods that could autofill an iPad?

Tags: ios, recovery, script, automation

I've recently went into a new IT job for my school and we're in the process of removing the activation lock on all of the school iPads. I was wondering if I could hook up my laptop (on Windows) to one of the iPads and run some sort of script (e.g. batch or Apple's auto) to select specified buttons upon entering the recovery setup and fill in each text entry with the necessary information.

Would this at all be possible? If so, what might I research to achieve it? My school uses Filewave MDM for its management.

Originally I used the iPad digital keyboard which was tedious and very accident prone, then I switched to an attachable keyboard which helped quite a bit. However, if possible, I wish to find a quicker and easier way.

Comment: Using softwares such as Meraki let you automate that to all devices on which you installed the profile. Feel free to ask for more info. ;)

Comment: Wondering why you're removing Activation Lock?

Comment: @Thinkr Would that not involve my entire school having to switch their MDM software over to Meraki?

Comment: @MarcWilson We're giving them to our elementary schoolers. I think it's because of the way filewave works but I'd have to look more into it

Comment: Oh. It does. So this means that you are already using a MDM software. That could be mentioned in the post. What software are you using? There might be a way with the one you're using now.

Comment: @Thinkr We're using filewave MDM.

Comment: I’m not familiar with that particular MDM software, but Microsoft Intune allows you to do exactly that; so it’s definitely possible.  You might want to contact the vendor to see what capabilities/training they offer

Comment: 30 sec with the Filewave Knowledge Base gives steps to remove Activation Lock .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for can be achieved natively from the MDM solution you're using (FileWave).

---

As per the [FileWave 13.2.2 Release](https://www.filewave.com/filewave-13-2-2-release/) article, the FileWave 13.2.2 release (in January 2020 - current version is 14.9) allows administrators to modify/set the Activation Lock parameter.

> New management features available in macOS 10.15 Catalina and iOS 13
>
> - New Inventory fields
> - Notarized FileWave components
> - ***Activation Lock***
> - And more

<sup>*Quote formatting mine (emphasis and italics)*</sup>

Note: This feature has also been mentioned in later FileWave release notes.

Comment: I think someone may have suggested that the activation lock can be wiped during restoration, although I'd have to ask more about it. Thanks!